# How to read property file that run in external jar

Tags: java

I have a Java project that contains a  jar file that include many properties files.
I am trying to read them and I can't find solution to my problem.
The path to the file when I copy it from Intellij looks like that:

/Users/my.name/Proj/projName/build/libs/projName.jar!/ui/pages/my/systemConfiguration/management/config.properties.

I don't have any ideas how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: .jar is essentially a zip file, if you don't really need the actual program, u can unzip it and get those config files

Comment: try adding the jar to the project's buildpath

Comment: You should add some more information about how exactly you are trying and how this is failing.

Comment: Eventually this solved it.
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream.